# How can I hash bigger text file than 16kB?

Tags: c++, hash, cryptography, crypto++

I'm using Crypto++ library for hashing. How can I hash bigger file than 16kB (string size)? I want hash files like 1Mb at least.

The error I am getting is when the text is bigger then 16kB:

```
error C2026: string too big, trailing characters truncated
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
std::string hash;
CryptoPP::SHA512 sha;

CryptoPP::StringSource ss(source, true,
                          new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha,
                              new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
                                  new CryptoPP::StringSink(hash))));

cout << "SHA-512 hash: " << hash << endl;
```

Comment: Where did you run into problems?

Comment: When I want hash bigger text then 16kB: error C2026: string too big, trailing characters truncated

Comment: Isn't that a compiler error, which tells you that you can't use string literals that long? In that case you could simply build the string in another way, e.g. by reading from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm using Crypto++ library for hash how can I hash bigger file than 16kB (string size)? I want hash files like 1Mb at least.

You should do either one of two things. First, use a [`FileSource`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSource) rather than a [`StringSource`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/StringSource). Something like:

```
string s1, s2, s3, s4;
SHA1 sha1; SHA224 sha224; SHA256 sha256; SHA512 sha512;

HashFilter f1(sha1, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s1)));
HashFilter f2(sha224, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s2)));
HashFilter f3(sha256, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s3)));
HashFilter f4(sha512, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s4)));

ChannelSwitch cs;
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f1);
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f2);
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f3);
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f4);

FileSource fs("filename.xxx", true /*pumpAll*/, new Redirector(cs));

cout << Message: " << message << endl;
cout << "SHA-1: " << s1 << endl;
cout << "SHA-224: " << s2 << endl;
cout << "SHA-256: " << s3 << endl;
cout << "SHA-512: " << s4 << endl;
```

In general, you can swap in any [Crypto++ Source](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Category:Source) and things will just work.

Second, you can map a view of the file into your process and then repeatedly call `Put` in a loop. When you are finished consuming all the data in the file, call `MessageEnd` and then unmap the file. You call `Put` and `MessageEnd` on on the `ChannelSwitch` above because its the [`BufferedTransformation`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/BufferedTransformation) of interest.

On Windows, you map the view of a file with [MapViewOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On Linux, you use [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

When you map a view of a file, you will effectively have a in-memory byte array backed by disk. In this case, you would use an [`ArraySource`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ArraySource) instead of `StringSource` or `FileSource`.